# How to detect different sounds based on what im walking on. 2D Game

Tags: audio, 2d, terrain

Im really noob at coding, I know the basics, but I want an help to code a script who can detect on which terrain I'm walking on and make different sounds. On the internet there are some tutorials but they are for 3D Games, mine is a 2D Game so it's different. Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't until you show some trying...

Comment: I have a code for the sound of footsteps, but I don't know how to do it on my own for detecting terrain, I can show you the code of footsteps sound

Answer (score 0):

I would put the footstep sound in a "wrapper" method, and in that method include arguments/values that indicate the current terrain and manner-of-movement, if they matter.

For example:

```
playFootstep("grass", "jumping")
```

or:

```
playFootstep("gravel", "walking")
```

Then, in this method, select what sound file to play based on the parameters, and play it.

How do you currently play your footsteps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my footsteps code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Footsteps : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip[] clips;

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void Step()
    {
        AudioClip clip = GetRandomClip();
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
    }
    private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
    {
        return clips[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];
    }
}
```